# Why do we need Outbox pattern with Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, event-driven, idempotent

I do not understand why we need the Outbox pattern when we have Event Driven architecture with Kafka.

Kafka offers Message Delivery Guarantees as described [here](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka/design/delivery-semantics.html#:%7E:text=At%20most%20once%3A%20Messages%20are,be%20delivered%20more%20than%20once.), having idempoency on producers and consumers with "Exactly-Once". Isn't it sufficient?

In case of answers, please include an example.

Comment: I think you're forgetting that Kafka can go down, but the "outbox table" could remain up

Comment: @OneCricketeer sure, but when it comes up again, you will consume the messages from the offset

Comment: Offset of what? A table? Most tables I've worked with have timestamps, not offsets. In any case, I was just giving an example why using a table might be preferred. Similarly, if there are other apps other than just Kafka reading this table, then you'd use it too. Without more context of the problem you're trying to solve, it's hard to answer why you'd need an outbox or not

Comment: offset of the kafka topic, I mean when kafka comes back up, you continue reading from where you stopped, you dont lose the message, all ok. Anyway, probably i dont have good understanding and might be talking nonsense here..

Comment: Kafka consumers don't read from outbox tables. It's not a Kafka topic, it's a transactional database. There's a database client that would read from that (like Debezium), then *produce* to Kafka topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Exactly-Once Semantics Are Possible: Here’s How Kafka Does It](https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/) blog post:

> Note that exactly-once semantics is guaranteed within the scope of Kafka Streams’ internal processing only; for example, if the event streaming app written in Streams makes an RPC call to update some remote stores, or if it uses a customized client to directly read or write to a Kafka topic, the resulting side effects would not be guaranteed exactly once.

> Stream processing systems that only rely on external data systems to materialize state support weaker guarantees for exactly-once stream processing. Even when they use Kafka as a source for stream processing and need to recover from a failure, they can only rewind their Kafka offset to reconsume and reprocess messages, but cannot rollback the associated state in an external system, leading to incorrect results when the state update is not idempotent.

So it depends on what you are actually doing in your app and Kafka. If your processing is limited to the Kafka Streams internal processing only - then you do not need to use the transactional outbox.

I'm not a great Kafka expert but for example updating a database can be considered a side effect and unless you can somehow to use a distributed transaction between Kafka and the database then you might need to use the [transactional outbox](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transactional-outbox.html) (or change data capture - CDC  via [Transaction log tailing](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transaction-log-tailing.html)).

The scenario is quite common - you need to  atomically update the database and send messages to a message broker:

[image]